# executing script ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET application default page is Login.aspx.
In this page I check the Query string, if it is empty I load the page, but if query string has parameters I want to launch the application on client.
This is working when first I browse my application without parameters (`http://localhost/myApps`), and then browse the application with some parameters (`http://localhost/myApps?ID='test'`).
But if I directly browse the site with `http://localhost/myApps?ID='test'`, it is not working.

Following is the code of my Global.asax page

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext httpCurrent;
        httpCurrent = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string  currentURL;
        if (Request.QueryString.Count == 4)
        {
            string PID = Request.QueryString["PID"].ToString();
            string sid = Request.QueryString["acc_no"].ToString();
            string uid = Request.QueryString["userID"].ToString();
            string uname = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
            currentURL = "ViewImages.aspx?PID=" + PID + "&acc_no=" + sid + "&userID=" + uid + "&username=" + uname;
            httpCurrent.RewritePath(currentURL);
        }
        else
        {
            currentURL = "Login.aspx?";
            httpCurrent.RewritePath(currentURL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Source?

Comment: when user browse my application without any parameter I want to show the default page, but if user browse the application with parameters I want to run some server sode code ,don't want to show default page ?
--Shital

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick sample app and following worked for me

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
       c.RewritePath("form2.aspx");
    else
        c.RewritePath("form1.aspx");
    }
```